# What was the earliest werewolf myth?

Tags: mythical-creatures, myth-identification, comparative, werewolves

So, [the earliest werewolf I can find](http://www.theoi.com/Heros/Lykaon.html) is in Greek times.

But, was there ever an earlier werewolf myth?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's a wolf transformation in the [Epic of Gilgamesh](http://www.werewolves.com/gilgamesh/), and as written texts go they don't come any earlier. Although in this case it was a spell cast upon him and he never had a chance to transform back into human form.

There may of course be earlier oral mythology.

Comment: In Slavic mythology some Bogatyrs can freely transform into animals, to cover greater distances or to look from above.